# How to override an Activity's method in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, overriding

I want to override a method present in an Activity through a Fragment which is added in the activity.

I have following setup:

*BaseActivity*

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // gets triggered whenever I set a toolbar title
    // from an Activity or Fragment
    public boolean shouldLimitToolbarCharacters () {  
        return true;
    }
}
```

*BaseFragmentActivity*

```
public class BaseFragmentActivity extends BaseActivity implements ToolbarBehaviour {

    // override from BaseActivity and from ToolbarBehaviour
    @Override
    public boolean shouldLimitToolbarCharacters () {

        // instead send it to fragment somehow
        return true;
    }
}
```

*ToolbarBehaviour*

```
 // implemented by BaseFragmentActivity above
 interface ToolbarBehaviour {
     boolean shouldLimitToolbarCharacters();
 }
```

*BaseFragment*

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onAttach (Context context) {

        if (context instanceof ToolbarBehaviour) {

            ToolbarBehaviour toolbarBehaviour = (ToolbarBehaviour) context;

            // ?? now what
        }
    }
}
```

How do I override `BaseFragmentActivity`'s `shouldLimitToolbarCharacters()` from `BaseFragment` or its sub-fragments?

Whenever I trigger `shouldLimitToolbarCharacters()` from a sub-fragment of `BaseFragment`, it should use sub-fragment's provided overridden method for `shouldLimitToolbarCharacters()`.

Thanks.

Comment: can u tell me what actually you want to do?

Comment: Override a method of Activity from a Fragment.

Comment: Maybe better if you tell us what you want to do in terms of functionality. What you want is technically impossible since both `Activity` and `Fragment` are concrete classes and are not subclasses of each other.

Comment: right, I got my answer. I wanted to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665961/3682535). Technically, we can't override, I know.

Comment: yes would be better , so we can provide better solutions

Comment: Put some flag to the this method, and pass a value to the flag from fragment class. You can do it for example using interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a `method` of `fragment` inside `Activity` as in

**BaseFragmentActivity**

```
public class BaseFragmentActivity extends BaseActivity implements ToolbarBehaviour {

    BaseFragment fragment; // init in oncreate or something;

    // override from BaseActivity and from ToolbarBehaviour
    @Override
    public boolean shouldLimitToolbarCharacters () {
         if(fragment == null)
            return false;
          return fragment.shouldLimitToolbarCharacters(); 
    }
}
```

**BaseFragment**

```
 public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

          public boolean shouldLimitToolbarCharacters(){
            return true; // do what ever you want to do 
          }     

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can directly access the activity method through  `((BaseFragmentActivity )getActivity()).shouldLimitToolbarCharacters();`

and use like this

```
@Override
    public void onAttach (Context context) {

        if (context instanceof BaseFragmentActivity) {
         ((BaseFragmentActivity)getActivity()).shouldLimitToolbarCharacters();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I said **Override**, not call.